# MySQL Outer Join Giving Max Join Size Error

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, outer-join

I thought I knew how to do a simple outer join, but it appears that I am wrong.  I am new to MySQL, but I do have Oracle experience.

I have two tables that I want to query.  The first table is a members table.  The second table is called purchases.  Purchases contains a row for each item a member purchases.

The members table contains a little more than 2700 rows.  The purchases table contains a little less than 130,000 rows.

I eventually want to get a list of all members with a count of their unique item purchases.  Here is my query:

```
select mem.member_id
      ,mem.name
      ,count(distinct pur.item_id)
from members mem
    left outer join purchases pur on mem.member_id = pur.member_id
```

I get the following error when I execute the query:

```
1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

The MAX Join Size is currently set to 7 million.

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine, but if that's obviously failing, you might try the following

```
select
      m.member_id,
      m.`name`,
      coalesce( cnts.UniqItems, 0 ) as UniqItems
   from
      members m
         left join ( select p.member_id, count( distinct p.item_id ) as UniqItems
                        from purchases p
                        group by p.member_id ) cnts
            on m.member_id = cnts.member_id
```

After writing, I think the problem may be the reserved word "NAME" for the column and should probably just need to be wrapped in `tic` marks to differentiate the column vs reserved word.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to wrap the "name" column in tic marks, but that didn't help.  I also tried to take out the count and just select member_id and name, but still got the error.

The query you supplied worked.  I can't say that I fully understand why.  Thanks for you help on this!